# Drowdown is not selectable

Tags: selenium, html-select, cucumber-java

I am trying to select some value in the  drop-down but I am getting the error

This is the code I am using to select the drop-down value. The dropdown is not opening.

```
<select ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" id="" ng-reflect-model="GT" title="" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="input-select__select ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
<option value="GT" ng-reflect-value="GT">&gt;
</option><option value="LT" ng-reflect-value="LT">&lt;
</option><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--></select></bss-input-select><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></div>


 
code :
WebElement dropdown = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class=\"input-select__select ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched\"]"));
            Select selectDropdownItem = new Select(dropdown);
            selectDropdownItem.selectByValue(dropDownItem);


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MijJI.png
```

Comment: Please attach html code as image. Attach your code which have error and attach error text. That will help people to provide you help.

Comment: I am not able to add a screenshot here   https://i.stack.imgur.com/MijJI.png

Comment: Great job. "dropDownItem" variable is not defined it shoud be repleaced with "GT". Do you have issues with xpath or at line
selectDropdownItem.selectByValue(dropDownItem);

Comment: I have issues with XPath.

Comment: getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='input-select__select ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']")); use this. If you still having issues try sleep just to see is it loding, and if it is use smart wait. If no Try getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-pair_input-text']/select[@class='input-select__select ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']"));